# How to use compose environment variables in docker ENTRYPOINT

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Environment variables don't appear to work in `ENTRYPOINT`. It is my understanding that the shell form of `ENTRYPOINT` will expand `ENV` variables at run time, but this doesn't to appear to work for `ENV_CONFIG_INT` in the example below. What have I done wrong in the following example?

*Dockerfile*

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "yarn", "run", "app-${ENV_CONFIG_INT}" ]
```

*Compose yaml*

```yaml
test:
    image: testimage/test:v1.0
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file:
        - ./docker.env
    environment:
        - ENV_CONFIG_INT=1
```

**Error:**

```sh
error Command "app-${ENV_CONFIG_INT}" not found.
```

Replacing the value with a static int of say 1 fixes the issue, however I want the value to be dynamic at runtime.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't try to use an environment variable to specify the command to run.  Remove the line you show from the Dockerfile, and instead specify the `command:` in your `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
test:
  image: testimage/test:v1.0
  build: .
  env_file:
    - ./docker.env
  command: yarn run app-1  # <--
```

As you note, the [shell form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example) of `ENTRYPOINT` (and `CMD` and `RUN`) will expand environment variables, but you're not using the shell form: you're using the [exec form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example), which doesn't expand variables or handle any other shell constructs.  If you remove the JSON-array layout and just specify a flat command, the environment variable will be expanded the way you expect.

```sh
# Without JSON layout
CMD yarn run "app-${ENV_CONFIG_INT:-0}"
```

(I tend to prefer specifying `CMD` to `ENTRYPOINT` for the main application command.  There are two reasons for this: it's easier to override `CMD` in a plain `docker run` invocation, and there's a useful pattern of using `ENTRYPOINT` as a wrapper script that does some initial setup and then runs the `CMD`.)

Comment: That was a very informative thank you. As suggested, if i remove the ENTRYPOINT isn't it standard practice to specify at least one ENTRYPOINT or CMD?

Comment: Providing a default `CMD` is good practice.  I generally think of Compose `command:` as an override, though in this case where each container needs a different command line it's appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

The usual way to ensure that environment variable expansion works in the entrypoint or command of an image is to utilize bash - or sh - as the entrypoint.

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  test:
    image: alpine
    environment:
      FOO: "bar"
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo $${FOO}"]
```

```sh
$ docker-compose run test
Creating so_test_run ... done
bar
```

The other thing you need to do is properly escape the environment variable, so its not expanded on the host system.